# ** ionic build --prod** build gives FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. i went in advanced system setting-> Environment variables Add New "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=7168" but still getting same error[JavaScript heap out of memory].I have 8GB RAM system. 
`[enter image description here][1]`
`[enter image description here][2]`
**Package.json**

`````
    "name": "@chat21/chat21-ionic",
    "version": "1.0.16",
    "author": "Dario De Pascalis - Frontiere21 SRL",
    "license": "AGPL-3.0",
    "homepage": "https://www.tiledesk.com",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/chat21/chat21-ionic"
    },
    "private": false,
    "bin": {
        "chat21-ionic": "./bin/chat21-ionic"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",

        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -d ./docs/ -p ./tsconfig.json",
        "postinstall": "ionic cordova platform add browser --save && ionic cordova build browser",
        "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=7168 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/common": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/compiler": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/core": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/forms": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/http": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.9",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/push": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.2.0",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "add": "^2.0.6",
        "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
        "build": "^0.1.4",
        "cordova": "^9.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
        "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-osx": "4.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
        "device": "^0.3.9",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "firebase": "5.9.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.4",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "4.5.5",
        "macos": "0.0.1",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "npm": "^6.13.1",
        "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.2.3",
        "promise-polyfill": "8.1.0",
        "rxjs": "6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "^1.1.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.29"

    },
    "resolutions": {
        "grpc": "^1.12.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^7.3.6",
        "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy": "^1.5.9",
        "typescript": "3.1.6"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [
        "ios",
        {
            "platform": "ios",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "ios"
        }
    ],
    "description": "listaUtenti: An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": {},
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "phonegap-plugin-push": {
                "SENDER_ID": "10454545458"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "browser",
            "osx"
        ]
    }



}````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1sZV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxurd.png
`````

Answer (score 2):

I think you have used a firebase in your project.

I've found a solution which was pointed out in an old message on the forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/3-7-0-ios-build-with-prod-not-working/107061/24

Open node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js

Change the first line from:

## !/usr/bin/env node

into

## !/usr/bin/env node --max-old-space-size=4096

I tried values 1024 and 2048, but for my relatively large app I needed 4096.

Now I am able to run ionic cordova build android --prod --release with out the FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory error.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I have put !/usr/bin/env node --max-old-space-size=4096 on node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js but still getting the same Error